# Is their any advantage of using Insert Query in different form in sqlserver stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have seen some `Stored Procedures` written with following *two formats*:

```
Method 1:
Insert Into Tablname(col1,col2) values (@col1,col2)

Method 2:
Insert Into Tablname(col1,col2) select @col1,@col2
```

I am very curious to know whether is their any advantage of Method1 or Method2 ? reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not performance difference. It's just matter of preference.

But with Method:2 you can do something like below to insert multiple records:

```
Insert Into Tablname(col1,col2) 
select @col1,@col2
Union all
select @col2,col4
```

From SQL Server 2008 (Row Construction) onwards, you can do something like below with your method 1:

```
INSERT INTO Tablname (col1, col2)
VALUES (1, 'First'), (2, 'Second'), (3, 'Third');
```

For more info, check out [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/) link.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty the same.

The `INSERT INTO...SELECT` (*sort of a shortcut which*) allows you to insert records from the result of your `SELECT` statement, eg.

```
INSERT INTO FooBar(Col1, Col2)
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM sourceTable
```

Comment: hi @491243, i would like to let you know that, i have not used FROM clause just selecting the parameters that are passed to SP. So is their any difference any performance related?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE i just extended the explanation. basically, all are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this both are same. There is no performance difference between both. There is also one another method for insert multiple record in one single insert into statement.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Value)
VALUES (1, 'Test1'), (2, 'Test2'), (3, 'Test3');
```